# How to show empty text in smart-table when data is empty

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I am using smart table in my application. The smart-table is configured with static headers and pagination bar. The data is loaded via async request. When the data received is empty the smart-table is shown with headers and pagination-bar. I want to show empty-text in between. I've read all the [documentation](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/) but i didn't find any config that allows to set the empty text. How do i do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below the

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection"></tr>
```

Put another `tr` with `ng-if` or `ng-show` directive when the data is empty.

```
<tr ng-if="rowCollection.length == 0">
   // your message here
</tr>
```